# How do I get the microphone working on an Acer ZG8?

Tags: acer, microphone

Microphone is not working.  Any (quick) fix?

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC272X Analog [ALC272X Analog] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: what is the output of aplay -l?

Comment: **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC272X Analog [ALC272X Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the checkmark by the "Mute" isn't checked, in your sound preferences.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

by these steps :-

1. Run alsamixer
2. Unmute all the outputs by hitting “m”
3. Hit tab to go the capture settings
4. Highlight the “Mic” setting using the arrow keys.
5. Hit space to enable the microphone.
6. Highlight the “Capture” setting using the arrow keys.
7. Hit space to enable capture (note that just because you have volume
   bar here doesn’t mean it is enabled).
8. Hit escape.

Comment: Didn't do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried cleaning out the mic jack?  gunk in the jack could make the card detect a mic plugged in even though it should be using the built-in...

check /dev/snd for files ending in c.  these denote capture devices, if they're not present then you're stuffed from the start.

another user already noted the initialized as muted problem, but it's still something to re-check.

fire up audacity and check the input devices -- usually the third drop down under buttons -- to make sure you're using the appropriate mic(front/rear)

if you can select the appropriate mic and record in audacity but the default capture device is inappropriate then select the proper one in sound preferences.  some webcams may steal the mic, just something worth noting.